# KVC compliance test

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, kvc

Is there any tool, similar to LLVM's static analyzer, that wil test if an Objective C class is 100% KVC compliant?

Comment: What, for every possible key? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there are many classes that are KVC compliant for all possible keys. You need to specify a particular key when you talk about KVC compliance. If you have a list of keys it's pretty easy to test whether your class is KVC compliant for each of them, but you should also specify whether each key represents an attribute, to-one relationship, indexed to-many relationship, or unordered to-many relationship.

That said, the answer to your question as far as I'm aware is: No, there is no tool included with Xcode that tests the degree of KVC-compliance of a class. You could surely write one without too much trouble, though.